# how to add timeout to my loading activity

Tags: android, performance

when started, my android application loads some image from a remote server using an Asynchronous task. Sometimes, when the connection is too weak, it takes a long time to load and it's not great.
how can i add timeout to this task, so that if the activity can't load the images after 10 seconds for example, the user will get an error message

Answer (score 0):

use `AsyncTask` and then show the progress bar for 10 seconds. if it exceeds more than that 10 sec show the log message .

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;

    static class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... vals) {
            try {
                long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
                for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Attempt #" + i + " to server connection");
                    try {
                        //DO STUFF
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                            break;
                        }
                        try {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Sleeping for " + backoff + " ms before retry");
                            Thread.sleep(backoff);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted: abort remaining retries!");
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            return 400;
                        }
                        // increase backoff exponentially
                        backoff *= 2;
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ERROR", e);
            }
            return 400;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {

        }
    }
```

But I suggest you look at [Volley](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/474338138), Google's new networking library. That will serve you best. I use this code above in one of my upload methods

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net web services for get data from server then use below:

```
HttpTransportSE aht1 = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);
```

Where, URL is your connection url of webservices. here, it waits for 1 minute for get response. after that it throws error of timeout.